# Can I get this latest update off my phone (Galaxy S4, Lollipop)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Can I get this latest update off my Galaxy S4 phone? I can't handle the color changes and need it off my phone.

Comment: Are you rooted and/or do you have a custom recovery?  The latter will likely be necessary.

Comment: The TouchWiz color scheme, *sigh*. Anyway, is this possible without tripping Knox?

Answer (score 1):

If you updated your phone to android 5.0 through Samsung OTA updates. Then I'm sorry. You can't go back because you updated your Knox boot loader. One thing you can do is install Cyanogenmod 12.